# Writing a service for Sending and Receiving UDP Packets android

Tags: android, sockets

I'm developing a app which Send and Receive data in a local Network. I decided to Write a service which Listen for incoming UDP Packets and when a packet Received from other devices the service report back the incoming message via a callback to the activity to update the view.and from the activity i call a method on the service to send it to a desired destination.
First I want to know that if my approach logic is correct and I chose the right tool(a service) for this matter.
and also there is a problem with the listening method on the service which this is the code. It gives the error on the **receive method**:

```
public class WifiService extends Service {


private final IBinder mBinder = new WifiBinder();
private WifiInterface serviceCallbacks;
public WifiService() {

}

public class WifiBinder extends Binder {
    WifiService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return WifiService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
public void setCallbacks(WifiInterface callbacks) {
    serviceCallbacks = callbacks;
}
public String Listen_Report() {
    String msg = "";
    try {
        while (true) {
            byte[] IncommingBuffer = new byte[1000];
            InetAddress localaddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.1");
            DatagramSocket rsc = new DatagramSocket(8008, localaddress);
            DatagramPacket dgp = new DatagramPacket(IncommingBuffer, IncommingBuffer.length);
            rsc.receive(dgp);
            msg = new String(dgp.getData(), 0, dgp.getLength());
            serviceCallbacks.ReportBack(msg);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return msg;
}
public void Sendmsg(final InetAddress dst, final String msg) throws IOException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length,
                        dst, 8008);
                DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
                dsocket.send(packet);
                dsocket.close();
            }

            catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

   }
}
```

And this is the **interface** :

```
public interface WifiInterface {
void ReportBack(String msg);
}
```

and this is the **part of the activity**:

```
btnRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mService.Listen_Report();

        }
    });
 btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                mService.Sendmsg(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.83"),"From Activity");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WifiService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        WifiService.WifiBinder binder = (WifiService.WifiBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
        mService.setCallbacks(mainMenu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};


@Override
public void ReportBack(String msg) {
    txtRec.setText(msg);
}
```

Comment: The service should be contacted by other activities using messages and not direct function calls. See this sample: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should have said which error you're receiving, but I suposse it's a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

First, you're calling this:

```
btnRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mService.Listen_Report();

    }
});
```

From the main thread.
And even if you use BroadcastMessages to comunicate with the service (as Ata told you), the service run on the main thread, so you'll have the same problem.

You have to run the receive method in another thread, just as you did with the send method.

```
public void Receivemsg() throws IOException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       while (true) {
            byte[] IncommingBuffer = new byte[1000];
            InetAddress localaddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.1");
            DatagramSocket rsc = new DatagramSocket(8008, localaddress);
            DatagramPacket dgp = new DatagramPacket(IncommingBuffer, IncommingBuffer.length);
            rsc.receive(dgp);
            msg = new String(dgp.getData(), 0, dgp.getLength());
            serviceCallbacks.ReportBack(msg);
        }
    }
    }).start();

   }
}
```

And then:

```
public void Listen_Report() 
{
    try 
    {
        Receivemsg();
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And finally (as the callback will be called outside the main thread)

```
@Override
public void ReportBack(String msg) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            txtRec.setText(msg);
        }
    }

}
```